# What is the regular expression in C# to find the word starting with / or \ and end with .js extension

Tags: c#

What is the regular expression in C# to find the word starting with `/` or `\` and ending with `.js`

Comment: You can use `String.StartsWith` and `String.EndsWith` methods.

Comment: Can you provide an example of input and expected output?

Comment: Now I get you. Look at [`System.IO.Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename) and [`System.IO.Path.GetExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension)

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern could look like this:

```
string pattern = @"^((\\|/).*?\.js)$";
Regex re = new Regex(pattern);
string file ="/whatever.js";
if (re.IsMatch(file)) 
{
   //Match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly C#:

```
^[\\\/].*\.js$
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with

```
"^((\\|/).*\.js)$";
```

Comment: i use tool in order to generate my regex, and that's false because my is without your interrogation on regex, verify not equals

Answer (score 0):

This will match an alpha numeric string starting with either \ or / and ending with .js

```
[\\/]\w+\.js
```

You can use anchors (previously assertions) to specify it must be at a word boundary or the start/end of a string if needed - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

not tested, but you can try putting the `/` or `\` in a character class, like:

- `'[\]'` or `"[/]"`
- `'[\]'` or `"[/]"`